# Como determinar uma covariável no modelo ANOVA (r)

Tags: r, anova

Eu tenho o seguinte modelo:

```
modelo = aov(y ~ tratamento + idade, data = dt)
```

Como eu faço pra determinar que a `idade` seja uma covariável, é um comando especifico, ou o modelo entende pelos níveis da variável em questão.

Comment: acredito que se postar junto um exemplo de dados, será mais fácil de te auxiliarem

Comment: Acredito que não precisa, pq é pra dizer que a `idade` é uma covariável.

Comment: Eu não entendi porque `idade` não seria considerada como covariável na sintaxe `aov(y ~ tratamento + idade, data = dt)`. Sem fornecer os dados ou ao menos o output do comando `summary(modelo)`, fica impossível que alguém consiga te ajudar.

Comment: @MarcusNunes, entendi desculpe pensei que fosse algo mais especifico, tentei melhorar minha pergunta. Mas descobri como funciona.

Comment: Isso é questão de nomenclatura. Para o @CuriousG. , se a coluna tem a classe (`class`) "factor" então é um "tratamento" e se for "integer", "numeric" é uma covariável. Fico me perguntando como ele classifica "character", "complex", "Date" e "logical". Para mim tudo do lado do x's é covariável.

Comment: @MárcioMocellin, mas o R entende que tudo do lado do x's é covariável? Pelo que eu vi a tabela da ANOVA muda com a nomenclatura.

Comment: Esta discussão é inútil sem que os outputs de `summary(modelo)` ou `str(dt)` sejam fornecidos. Do jeito que a questão foi colocada, `idade` pode estar definida em anos, o que implica que é uma variável com 1 grau de liberdade na tabela ANOVA (ou ANCOVA, se quisermos ser preciosistas). Ou `idade` pode ser um fator com `k` níveis para intervalos de, digamos, cinco anos. Neste caso, `idade` apareceria na tabela ANOVA com `k-1` graus de liberdade, em que `k` é o número de níveis de `idade`. Todos aqui, exceto o AP, estão tateando no escuro. Faltam informações para darmos uma resposta definitiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agradeço, aos comentários acima. De fato, para determinar uma variável como fator ou covariável, é como a mesma está classificada no banco de dados. Como fator ou numérica, para saber como ela está classificada (formato), basta usar o `str` para saber estas informações, no meu caso `str(dt)`. Para a variável ser considerada uma covariável basta estar no formato numérico, enquanto para ser "tratamento" no formato fator. Espero ter sido claro. Sugestões para melhorar minha resposta são bem vindas.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, realmente sem algumas informações como já mencionado, fica um pouco obscuro.

Da próxima vez tente fazer um `dput()` pra que possamos ajudar melhor. Caso não queira exibir os dados originais, crie um df que contenha o básico.

De todo modo penso que vc queira o seguinte:

```
modelo = lm(y ~ tratamento + factor(idade), data = dt)
anova(modelo)
```